# Cannot open logical volume in C (Windows)

Tags: c, handle, read-write, createfile

I'm struggling to open a handle to a logical drive in C; the code that I am currently working on is:

```
int main ()
{
    HANDLE hvol = CreateFile("\\\\.\\T:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(hvol==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Failure");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned char sector[512];
    DWORD bytesread;
    ReadFile(hvol, sector, sizeof sector, &bytesread, NULL);

    printf("%02x", sector[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't get past the `createfile` line - "Failure" is returned every time implying that the volume cannot be opened.

I have also tried:

`"\\\\?\\Volume{eed5cc92-0000-0000-0000-60b21b000000}"` (The GUID for the volume)

`"\\\\.\\T:"` (Other posts have suggested this)

None of which worked.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Do write better error reporting code, at least display the value returned by GetLastError() so you *know* why it failed.

Comment: Perhaps it is down to file permissons - The person running the code and the owner of the resource

Comment: According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/100027/info-direct-drive-access-under-win32) you need to specify FILE_SHARE_READ and FILE_SHARE_WRITE flags. Also, as mentioned, `GetLastError()` is your friend.

Comment: I have now set both READ and WRITE flags in the `CreateFile` line. `GetLastError()` returned "file not found" before, and now error code 5 "access is denied". I am the owner and have full control over the volume so any additional ideas would be great.

Comment: Just an idea. Try opening an existing file for reading in the same folder you are expecting to write into, see if that throws any light.

Comment: Maybe volume is already opened?